# Why is my field null even though it should be instantiated immediately?

Tags: java, class, field, instantiation, operator-precedence

The fields I am declaring and immediately instantiating are `null`. Here is a sample code:

```
public class NullFieldSSCCE {

    static abstract class Parent {
        List<String> values;
        Parent() {
            values = getValues();
        }

        protected abstract List<String> getValues();   
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {

        String param1="test1";
        String param2="test2";

        Child() {
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getValues() {
            return Arrays.asList( new String[] {param1, param2} );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();

        System.out.println("Child p1="+child.values.get(0)+", p2="+child.values.get(1));
    }

}
```

The result of running this is

```
Child p1=null, p2=null
```

while I would expect

```
Child p1=test1, p2=test2
```

How is this possible? These fields are instantiated at the same moment the class is, aren't they?

Comment: You will probably have got a warning about using a non final method within your constructor being bad; this is why

Comment: @RichardTingle no warning

Comment: Thats odd, I get an "Overridable method call in constructor" warning with your SSCCE. What are you using, an IDE or command line?

Comment: @RichardTingle Eclipse 4.2.0, JDK 7u05

Comment: I've had a bit of an investigate and it may be a netbeans specific hint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What is happening

What you have encountered is described in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) in chapters `8.3.2` and `8.8`. You can find some less detailed and perhaps easier to read information [here](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html).

**The issue here is the order of initialization of an object.**

Here is the order of initialization for your example:

1. `Parent` fields are instantiated: `values` becomes an instance of `ArrayList`
2. `Child` constructor calls `super()`, hence invoking `Parent` constructor
3. `getValues()` is called; in this case, it is `Child.getValues()`;
4. `Child` fields are instantiated: `param1` and `param2` have their values assigned
5. `Child` constructor continues - and does nothing more in your case

You assumend that all fields from all the classes in given hierarchy are instantiated at the same time, that `4` happens before `3` and roughly at the same time as `1`. This assumption is, unfortunately, wrong.

### Learning the initialization order

Even if you have read the links I have given you, you may not be certain how things will work in a specific case. Whenever you have doubts about order of initialization do not hesitate to add `printf`s to check it. I've done it for you this time:

```
public class NullFieldSSCCE {

    static abstract class Parent {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>() {{
          System.out.println("Parent.values instantiation");  
        }};

        Parent() {
            System.out.println("Parent()");
            values.addAll(getValues());
        }

        protected abstract List<String> getValues();   
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {

        String param1="test1";
        String param2="test2";
        Object param3 = new Object() {{System.out.println("Child.param3 instantiation"); }};

        Child() {
            System.out.println("Child()");
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getValues() {
            System.out.println("Child.getValues()");
            return Arrays.asList( new String[] {param1, param2} );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        Child child = new Child();

        System.out.println("Child p1="+child.values.get(0)+", p2="+child.values.get(1));
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
start
Parent.values instantiation
Parent()
Child.getValues()
Child.param3 instantiation
Child()
Child p1=null, p2=null
```