# Java collection property initialisation - best practice

Tags: java

Age old problem, but what's the best practice here?

Four examples off the top of my head:

```
//================
public class POJO{
  List<String> list;
}

//================
public class POJO{
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}

//================
public class POJO{
  List<String> list;

  public POJO(){
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
}

//================
public class POJO{
  List<String> list;

  public getList(){
      if (list==null)
        list =new ArrayList<String>();
      return list;
  }
}
```

I'm asking because I've got client facing POJOs that initialise to null and domain objects that are returning empty collections when they query the database and miss (but they will insert nulls).  I think I need to do one or the other but can't decide which.

Comment: Generally it's best to initialize a collection by its interface followed by the actual implementation. So the following: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: this is what I normally do.  Just needed a sanity check.  Working from home can do that to you.

Comment: Technically, this question ought to be closed as "primarily opinion based". I won't vote for that, though - I think this is a valid question and will be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one:

```
public class POJO {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: this is what I normally do.  Just needed a sanity check.

Comment: Agree that #2 is best. Just don't assume others will do the same! I have seen all of 1,2,3,4 in practise.

Comment: @MDrabic I think (needs to be checked) that both compile to the same result, so no impact at runtime. And the time difference at compile time is neglectible.

Comment: Considering the initial capacity for the list would be helpful in situations where we know in advance how much it could grow

Answer (score 0):

This is more about the coding conventions followed in your project than a pest practice. As long as all of you do it the same way, there is very little difference in the methods.

Except for #1 which probably should initialize the field explicitly to null if null is an acceptable value.

```
List<String> list = null;
```

Comment: If you're the sole coder, then I guess you define the conventions.  Hence the question!

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter then as long as you do it the same way everywhere. This is a very minor detail. Don't fret over it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The third one.

Putting these initializers in the constructor leaves no place for weird order-of-initialization problems like my own, here: [Why is my field null even though it should be instantiated immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488746/why-is-my-field-null-even-though-it-should-be-instantiated-immediately) The hidden call to `super()` at the start of the constructor is better known than the detailed order of initialization in general.

Answer (score 0):

The second one, as long as you dont wanna be checking in each op over the list if it's null. Also, when fetch from database u make sure to get the elements persisted in list or at least a empty collection, avoiding NPEs.

```
public class POJO { List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); }
```

Answer (score -1):

The third one:

```
//================
public class POJO{
  List<String> list;

  public POJO(){
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
}
```

There's usually work in the constructor anyways; with #3 it's all there. With #2 you have to look in two places.

My take on this:

```
class MyClass {
  // constants first
  public static final int CONSTANT_1 = 48;

  // private static stuff next
  private static final Logger logger = ...;

  // private final stuff
  private final String property;

  // private non-final stuff, with good comments

  // protected stuff, with VERY good comments

  MyClass() {
    // the only place things get initialized
  }
}
```

Comment: What about if it's a basic POJO, where there's often no need for a constructor?  The constructor would just be there for initialising the list.

Comment: Personally I'd still throw it in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

3rd one as it is a lazy initilaisation which is a prefered design.

Comment: you mean the 4th one? That's kinda ugly, actually, getters should be brainless

Comment: You're mixing several things. Lazy initialization is used when an object is long to initialize and you prefer to have a small startup time. A POJO is supposed to be simple. Such a getter is not "simple".

Comment: @Ogregoire I know what Lazy initialisation is, also its good practice to have it not only in terms of small startup time but in terms of memory as well. Guy has mentioned POJO, and you are mixing things, a POJO is ultimately an java object, tagging it POJO doesnt make it different. If we have a lazy initialisation in POJO , I dont see any loss..After all it depends on your need

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the object only in the constructor.

```
public class POJO{
  private List<String> list = null;

  public POJO(){
    this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why only in the constructor? And in your example, you're initializing it twice, first to `null` and then in the constructor.

Comment: I sometimes use such initialization as a mark, that this object being null just after instantiation is intentional. In this case this serves no purpose for me.